# "The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification" Error on listview

Tags: java, android, multithreading, listview, android-listview

This error is Showing often "The content of the adapter has changed but `ListView` did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread."
Getting the `NewsList` and other images and ads from API using `JSON`.

```
class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {


        AdSpotList.add(sched);
        Image_view_List.add(sched);
        NewsList.add(sched);

        handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {


    }
}
Handler handler = new Handler() {

    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

        if (msg.what == 1) {
                if (NewsList.size() != 0) {

                    if (NewsList.size() <= 5) {

                        adapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(),
                                Image_view_List, NewsList, AdSpotList, res);

                        lv_daily_summary.setAdapter(adapter);

                    } else { 
                        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                lv_daily_summary.invalidateViews();
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
                            }
                        });

                    }
                }
            }
    }
};
```

This complete page is on the Fragment.

Comment: Why are you using `Handler` if u r using `AsyncTask`. Update your adapter in `onPostExecute()` method.

Comment: Okay but In my api I will receive two different case of result one is "success" another one is "failure", for success alone has the newsList value so I used the handler.

Comment: No no. You just in `onPostExecute()` method you need to check  if it is success you just need to set your adapter. This error occurs when you'r not update your UI in UI thread instead of update on your main thread.